# Copyright Images laws

Tags: copyright

I have heard in the past that editing an image to make it significantly different than its original form will allow you to use it without worrying about copyright laws. Is this true?

Answer (score 2):

### No

What you describe is a [derivative work](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative_work) and the right to make them rests with the copyright owner.